# How to create a process by a "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress" alike argument?

Tags: c++, process

I want to create a **process** with syntax similar to the following,except that I don't want to create a **thread**：

```
     hThread = CreateThread( 
        NULL,              // no security attribute 
        0,                 // default stack size 
        InstanceThread,    // thread proc
        (LPVOID) hPipe,    // thread parameter 
        0,                 // not suspended 
        &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID
```

But I've checked the reference for [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) and a sample :

```
BOOL result = ::CreateProcess(
  L"C:\\Windows\\NOTEPAD.exe",
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  FALSE,
  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  &startupInfo,
  &processInformation
);
```

It seems I must specify an existing executable to create a process? How can I create one by a callback similar to `InstanceThread` ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.  Processes and threads are different.  You cannot create a process by just giving the address of a function in your executable.

You could, however, create your process with some command-line argument that your process reads and then uses to call the target function you want.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Then is it possible to create a thread that can still survive after the main thread is dead?

Comment: You can have your main thread wait for the completion of your background thread.  Use `WaitForSingleObject` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx)  to join the threads, e.g. `WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, INFINITE);`

Comment: No,I don't want the main thread to wait,but die(),leave the created thread still alive.

Comment: Your process won't terminate until *all* threads have exited.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Technically true, but note that some CRT implementations on Windows call ExitProcess(), terminating all threads, after main() returns. As a result, Alan is partly right: he cannot return from main() and rely on the OS keeping his other thread alive. The main thread should die violently (TerminateThread)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look how cygwin implements `fork()`. Unix `fork()` is what you want here.